# How to deal with asynchronous function in angular guar?

Tags: angular, function, asynchronous, guard

i have a problem with deal asynchronous function  in asynchronous function in angular guard, guard below first return undefined isLogged value, and after that true isLogged value what i want return. Can someone help me with this easy problem?

```
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) { }
  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.checkIfUserIsLogged()) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    return false;
  }

  private checkIfUserIsLogged(): boolean {
    if (!window.indexedDB) {
      console.log(`Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB.`);
    }
    let isLogged;
    const request = indexedDB.open(DB.NAME);
    request.onsuccess = () => {
      const userName = localStorage.getItem('user');
      const db = request.result;
      const tx = db.transaction(DB.OBJECT_STORE, 'readwrite');
      const store = tx.objectStore(DB.OBJECT_STORE);
      const logoutRequest = store.get(userName);
      logoutRequest.onsuccess = () => {
        console.log(logoutRequest.result.isLogged);
        logoutRequest.result.isLogged ? isLogged = true : isLogged = false;
      };
      return isLogged;
    };
    console.log(isLogged);
    return isLogged;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you work with asynchronous  you must be careful because the value is returned when  the function is process and not immediately, so the compile goes away until the value is process. I think your problem is here:

```
      private checkIfUserIsLogged(): boolean {
                    if (!window.indexedDB) {
                      console.log(`Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB.`);
                    }
                    let isLogged=false; // start with false
                    const request = indexedDB.open(DB.NAME);
                    request.onsuccess = () => {
                      const userName = localStorage.getItem('user');
                      const db = request.result;
                      const tx = db.transaction(DB.OBJECT_STORE, 'readwrite');
                      const store = tx.objectStore(DB.OBJECT_STORE);
                      const logoutRequest = store.get(userName);
                      logoutRequest.onsuccess = () => {
                        console.log(logoutRequest.result.isLogged);
                        logoutRequest.result.isLogged ? isLogged = true : isLogged = false;
                return logoutRequest.result.isLogged; //you need to return now the value whe the on success is processed
                      };
return false;

                  };
    return false;
        }
```

Comment: in case you propose this function not returing boolean ;/

Answer (score 0):

You need to return either a promise or an observable as you're running some async code and then immediately ignoring it.

The code as it stands will effectively ignore your onSuccess and always return undefined (the "value" of `isLogged`);

Instead, return an observable (similar to a promise - will return a result at some point in the future) and then pass the value into the subject from inside the onsuccess callback.

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  // return an observable - a value that will return at some point in the future
  return this.checkIfUserIsLoggedIn().pipe(
    tap(loggedIn => {
      // it has now run. tap is one way of getting to the result and doing something
      if(!loggedIn) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
      }
    });
  );
}

private checkIfUserIsLogged(): Observable<boolean> {
    if (!window.indexedDB) {
      console.log(`Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB.`);
      return of(false);
    }

    const subject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

    const request = indexedDB.open(DB.NAME);
    request.onsuccess = () => {
      const userName = localStorage.getItem('user');
      const db = request.result;
      const tx = db.transaction(DB.OBJECT_STORE, 'readwrite');
      const store = tx.objectStore(DB.OBJECT_STORE);
      const logoutRequest = store.get(userName);
      logoutRequest.onsuccess = () => {
        console.log(logoutRequest.result.isLogged);
        const isLogged = logoutRequest.result.isLogged;

        // Trigger the observable. The calling code will now run the pipe.
        subject.next(isLogged);
        subject.complete();
      };       
    };

    return subject.asObservable();        
  }
```

Comment: still when i call subject.next(isLogged) its pass undefined value

Comment: Oops, my mistake. I didn't actually move .next() into the callback